# helm generated secret keeps getting recreated

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-secrets

I have a secret, which was generated via helm.
After i deleted the helm install (including --purge), the secret is instandly recreated.
I figure the type (`kubernetes.io/tls`) plays into that. The odd thing is, that this worked before.

The question would be:
How to remove it forever?

thank you and best regards,
scones

Comment: What secret is this? Does this behaviour reproduce on different secrets your manage with Helm?

Comment: the secret-type is `kubernetes.io/tls` as stated above. it is a type used by cert-manager and it was created and managed by helm. helm itself is a bit flunky, when it comes to deletion of secrets. usually it is enough to reinstall the chart and delete-purging the chart again. not this time. neither helm, nor a manual delete can get rid of it. i did not have this problem on any other secret again since then.

Comment: @scones Can you remember what you did if you fixed it?. I just ran into a similar issue where on production server where I cannot delete a secret even after "worse case scenario"...helm delete. They keep re-appearing and have no pods using them! I didn't generate secrets with helm, but my app is.

Comment: those secrets in my case were certificate secrets. i went over and changed the roll-out design, as in: decoupled certificates from application. so i eliminated the need to always update or recreate the certificate along with the application in a deployment. had no problems since. i am aware this i no solution, but avoiding the pit might sometimes be as good.

Answer (score -2):

It doesn't make sense, might be a bug in helm. If helm created a resource, it's also responsible to clean it up when deleting the release...

Comment: this is not an answer to my question.

Comment: Why not? I specified it might be a bug in helm.. Just noticed that you mentioned "that the secret recreated" meaning, the age was a couple of MS? this might mean that something is watching it... Nothing should be able to create secrets... Can you try reproduce on a clean minikube environment?